# fold expression: right shift initialization behavior

Tags: c++, c++17, fold-expression

I am having fun with the fold expressions to understand better where I will be able to use them in my projects. So I choose to initialize them with a simple

```
(datas = ... = 1);
```

So far everything work as expected, every value is at 1. Then I tryed to use the left shift initialization so:

```
    (datas = ... = 1);
    (datas <<= ...);
```

Here is also work as I expect it, it increase by a power of 2 it's nice.
And finally I tryed this:

```
(datas = ... = 1);
(datas >>= ...);
```

And it give me as output a `0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, ...`, I expected it would be all at 0. So here the code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename... T>
void test(T&&... datas) {
    (datas = ... = 1);
    (datas >>= ...);
    (std::cout << ... << (std::to_string(datas) + " ")) << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int v1, v2, v3, v4;
    test(v1, v2, v3, v4);
    return 0;
}
```

Why it is `0, 1, 0, 1` etc instead of `0, 0, 0, 0` ? I through for every argument it will do more something like that:
`arg1 >>= arg2, arg2 >>= arg3, arg3 >>= arg4, etc`
but it's true that then the last value should be 1 then so it could also be `0, 0, 0, 1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is that way because your fold is

```
arg1 >>= arg2 >>= arg3 >>= arg4;
```

`arg3 >> arg4` is `1 >> 1`, so `arg3` becomes `0`.
Then, `arg2 >> arg3` is `1 >> 0`, so `arg2` becomes `1`.
Then, `arg1 >> arg2` is `1 >> 1`, so `arg1` becomes `0`.

Thus, `0, 1, 0, 1`.

I think the lesson here is "mutations and folds don't mix".

Answer (score 1):

`(datas >>= ...)` is equivalent to `d1 >>= (d2 >>= (d3 >>= d4));`

proof:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename...Ts>
void set(Ts&&... datas)
{
    (datas = ... = 1);
}

template<typename...Ts>
void print(Ts&&... datas)
{
    (std::cout << ... << (std::to_string(datas) + " ")) << std::endl;
}

template<typename... T>
void test(T&&... datas) {
    set(datas...);
    (datas >>= ...);
    print(datas...);
}

void test2(int& d1, int& d2, int& d3, int& d4)
{
    set(d1,d2,d3,d4);
    d1 >>= (d2 >>= (d3 >>= d4));
    print(d1,d2,d3,d4);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int v1, v2, v3, v4;
    test(v1, v2, v3, v4);
    test2(v1, v2, v3, v4);
    return 0;
}
```

expected results:

```
0 1 0 1 
0 1 0 1
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e0435451bcf8af70